# Expected Value of the Probability

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value

A paper I was reading they gave the following result without explanation:

Let $s\in\left\{0,1\right\}^n$ where the probability of 1 occurring is p. Let k be the number of 1s occurring in s. 
Then $\mathbf{E}[p|k]=\frac{k+1}{n+2}$ .

Intuitively, I would assume $f(p)=p^k*(1-p)^{n-k}$ to be the probability density function. But then I get $\mathbf{E}[p|k]=\int_{0}^{1}x^{k+1}*(1-x)^{n-k}$ which yields a different result.

I'm thankful for any tips! On a side note, I've only done first year probability, hence I'm not very capable.

Comment: That's the expected value of the Bayesian estimator for p given a uniform prior - have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2643324/bernoulli-uniform-bayes-estimator

Comment: the problem is in the order of 0 and 1. For example, for $k = 1$ you are counting $p(1-p)^{n-1}$, but in reality there are $n$ possible s's with this probability (hint: binomial)

Answer (score 1):

Your $f(p)$ is not a probability density function but is proportional to the likelihood. So if you have a uniform prior on $[0,1]$ then $f(p)$ is also proportional to the posterior; the scaling factor is essentially a Beta function so the probability density function would be $\dfrac{p^k(1-p)^{n-k}}{B(k+1,n-k+1)}$.

The mean of this posterior distribution would then be $$\dfrac{\int_0^1 p \cdot p^k(1-p)^{n-k} \, dp}{\int_0^1 \quad p^k(1-p)^{n-k} \, dp} = \dfrac{B(k+2,n-k+1)}{B(k+1,n-k+1)}=\dfrac{k+1}{n+2}$$

Comment: Thank you! The intuition is that p has a probability of 1 of being in the interval [0,1] and hence we scale $p^k*(1-p)^{n-k}$ to obtain the probability density function with the integral over [0,1] equalling 1, correct?

Comment: @Alison: Yes - that is an essential feature of a probability distribution